# merging csv files with no common column in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to join data from two CSV files, both of which have no common column and different number of rows. Is this possible in python?

I have two tables :
campaign_desc.csv and twitter.csv

campaign_desc : campaign , description , start_day , end_day
twitter.csv : user , tweet

I want to join any 2 columns from campaign_desc with the columns on twitter.csv but the result being limited to the number of rows in campaign_desc.

Comment: Of course it is. But you might not get anything reasonable out of it since you haven't explained *how* they should be merged

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I have edited my question, could be please guide me now!!

Comment: The way you are describing this, requires either a common index, or some modification of the CSV files.  The merging of the files is possible in python, but as described here, you will most likely get a mess that is indecipherable.